# Remove Session from URL String

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.NET 4 site, i get a lot of the url's with session string embedded in them. Because of this, the same page is indexed by the search engine multiple times, all with different session id's. Erlier i also used to have aspautodetectcookie string appended to the url. But i was able to remove it later.

How can I remove this session from the  url - forever.

If my url is http://www.somesite.com/ViewProduct.aspx?ID=12, i want it to show like that all the time.

Here are some settings in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/AccessDenied.aspx" name="FORMAUTH" />
        </authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="15" />

<anonymousIdentification cookieless="AutoDetect" enabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Change cookieless to "UseCookies" to have the session stored inside a cookie. Otherwise the session is embedded into the URL.

Here's more information from the [MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless.aspx)

Comment: ok how do I test if the problem has been fixed? I mean these session id's come randomnly in the url.

Comment: another question - if i set cookieless to true and if the client does not support cookies, what happens?

Comment: You'll be able to test this by visiting a page that would be using the session & causing a post back.

Comment: As for what happens if they're not supported, I believe it causes an error. If you need to support clients without cookies enabled you can set cookieless to "autoDetect". This will display the session string back in the URL for these clients.

Comment: I was just reading this article http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx and it says that adding cookieless = "true" session id 'will be' embedded in all page URLs. Can you explain what you meant and what this article says.